# What is the difference of MouseInputs and KeyInputs (To get the window in the foreground)

Tags: c++, winapi

Good day everybody.

It is so that one with SendInputs to send keys only has to call `SetForegroundWindow()` in order to bring the window into the foreground. This also works without problems.

Now it is so that one could think that with the mouse inputs the same procedure can be applied. But this was not possible. First you had to use the function `AttachThreadInput()` to get the window really in the foreground.

It is very confusing that it works with keys simply but with the mouse so cumbersome to be done. Can someone explain to me briefly why this is so?

Sorry for the title and the bad english, unfortunately, no other words have occurred to me.

Since it is too much code, I simply show the relevant for my question.

Keys:

```
if(SetForegroundWindow(window[id]))
{
 //SENDINPUT for key, works without any problems. (Not with Mouse)
}
```

Mouse:

```
AttachThreadInput(dwCurID, dwMyID, TRUE);
SetWindowPos(window, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
SetWindowPos(window, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
SetForegroundWindow(window);
AttachThreadInput(dwCurID, dwMyID, FALSE);
//The Window is now on foreground, now use SendInput for Mouse. This way works
```

So I wonder really why not both works in the way of the key example. So the reason I know since the window is not really in the foreground and this is necessary for the MouseInputs. One might think that it would also be necessary for the Keyevents. Hence my confusion.

I wish you happy day!

Comment: You need to show us actual code, the expected result and the actual result if you want proper help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly ... Yes, the keyboard and mouse input models are different.

But I think the real issue is that calling SetForegroundWindow on the window of another application is complicated.  Windows has a [long list of rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) of when you can and cannot set the foreground window.  (The intent is to make it hard for programs to push their windows in the user's face when the user wants to do something else.)  What seems to work when you're testing might not actually work reliably in real life.  For example, some of the rules depend on whether the current foreground window is owned by a process attached to a debugger.  My guess is that you got lucky when you tested the keyboard case and you found a way around the rules when you worked on the mouse case.

Keyboard input is directed to the window with the keyboard focus.  The window with keyboard focus is either the foreground window or a child of the foreground window.  So to direct keyboard messages with SendInput to a particular application, you only have to make sure it has focus, which you can do by bringing its window to the foreground.

If you succeed, then the window you just brought to the foreground will make sure the window focus is set appropriate (e.g., by calling SetFocus on one of its children).  If you were to try to call SetFocus yourself, on a window that belonged to another thread or process, you would first have to use AttachThreadInput just as you've done in the case for the mouse.  (This is explained in [SetFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646312(v=vs.85).aspx).)

Mouse input is (generally) directed to the window under the mouse, even if that window is not the foreground window.  The big exception is when a window has "captured" the mouse, then all mouse input goes to that window, even if the mouse is over a different window.  But the other exception is also the mouse scroll wheel messages, which seem to follow the window with keyboard focus.

I'm not entirely sure why (or whether) it's important to set the foreground window to send mouse input, unless it's because you're trying to make sure it gets the mouse scroll wheel messages.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you very much for your very good explanations as well as your time

Comment: Can you please describe this more precisely? (Current foreground window is own by a process attached to a debugger.) Maybe little example?

Comment: I should have said "owned."  I don't know all the rules in detail.  The link explains them better than I can.  The point is that if either your program or the program you're trying to call SetForegroundWindow on is being run in the debugger, than the rules are different.  You have to keep that in mind when trying things out, or you might make a change that appears to have made a difference when actually it's just that you're testing it differently.

Comment: Ok, thanks 2 Question to the condition.
1. The process is the foreground process.
In this case why should I use SetForegroundWindow when the process is already in the foreground? Do not make sense to me.

2.The process was started by the foreground process.
Did not each new process automatically start as a foreground process?